# Find the rule that assigns numbers to words

Tags: word, pattern

I have devised a rule that assigns a positive integer to each English word. Here is a list of words and the integers the rule assigns them.

| Word | Integer | Word | Integer | Word | Integer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| atmosphere | 3 | a | 1 | ab | 3 |
| day | 2 | beret | 1 | ad | 1 |
| eclipse | 7 | cheaters | 6 | bag | 1 |
| geology | 4 | coins | 2 | banana | 5 |
| heavy | 3 | dad | 5 | bann | 3 |
| inflation | 1 | fad | 2 | hear | 4 |
| neanderthal | 3 | hectares | 6 | her | 3 |
| parsimoniously | 4 | highways | 1 | males | 1 |
| span | 1 | I | 5 | prevent | 1 |
| zealous | 8 | laziness | 2 | snap | 1 |
|  |  | lid | 1 | thorny | 1 |
|  |  | transportation | 2 |  |  |

The rule can be described in a single sentence.

> What is my rule?

**Edit**: I have chosen some additional words and computed the numbers the rule assigns them. Also, find some hints below.

Hint 1:

> It is unlikely you will find a word in the dictionary that is assigned a value larger than 10. However, the rule is defined for arbitrary strings of English letters, and it is possible write down strings with arbitrarily large output. To get an output of 11 requires a string of at least 16 characters, and the 16 character string with output 11 that comes first alphabetically is "dzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz".

Hint 2:

> It might be useful to start by figuring out what the words assigned 1 have in common.

Hint 3:

> The US coins are: penny (1¢), nickel (5¢), dime (10¢), quarter (25¢), half dollar (50¢), and dollar (100¢). This is relevant.

Hint 4:

> The rule assigns anagrams the same number.

Hint 5:

> The rule does **not** depend on any of the following:
> Case, font, keyboard layout, letter frequency, word meaning

Hint 6:

> The longest string that the rule assigns 1 has one hundred letters.

Comment: What is the highest the integer assigned can be? Or is that a secret?

Comment: @JLee Let me leave that secret for right now. I might add that information as a hint after a while.

Comment: does meaning of word matters ?

Comment: Is zero ever a viable output?

Comment: Is the results constant over time?

Comment: The meaning of the words does not matter. The output is always strictly positive, never zero.

Comment: Regarding the results being constant over time: this could conceivably depend on how how one words the rule, and I'm worried about saying something technically false, so I think I won't answer the question right now. I can say that one doesn't need to own a watch or a calendar to figure out the rule.

Comment: I got nowhere using scrabble scoring

Comment: I really think the integer relies somewhat on the actual list or location the word is in.

Comment: @Raystafarian The integer depends only on the word itself, not on where it appears in the list or anything like that

Comment: Does one word can have multiple values?

Comment: @TroyAndAbed No, each word determines one (and only one) value

Comment: Hrm.  Does the rule involve finding a non-integer and rounding up?

Comment: Tried a bunch of unicode values and variations thereof, as well as remainder checking for different divisors - got no pattern of note

Comment: @Raystafarian - I was thinking ascii due to the USA hint, but (after an admittedly fairly cursory attempt) turned up nothing either.

Comment: Does the "_does not involve the keyboard layout_" apply to [LinoType keyboards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linotype_machine#/media/File:ClavierLinotype_20041006-163300.jpg)?

Comment: Are the letters of the words "penny", "nickel", "dime", "quarter", "half dollar", and "dollar" relevant at all?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have found the rule.

> Give each letter a value. A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, and so on. Then add all the values. I have taken "snap" as an example. "snap" = 19 + 14 + 1 + 16 = 50. Then find what is the least number of coins needed to make the total, or in this case, 50 cents. You only need one coin for a total of 50 cents. Therefore, 1 is the correct answer. As listed in a hint, the US coins are used: penny (1¢), nickel (5¢), dime (10¢), quarter (25¢), half dollar (50¢), and dollar (100¢).

Another example:

> cab = 3 + 1 + 2 = 6 cents = 5 cent coin + 1 cent coin = 2 coins

Comment: If you guys want to try this method out, use this code (JavaScript): `function SOLVE(v){x="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");v=v.split("");for(i=0,a=0;i<v.length;i++)a+=x.indexOf(v[i])+1;return c(a);}function c(a,f=Math.floor){S=f(a/100);a-=S*100;T=f(a/50);a-=T*50;U=f(a/25);a-=U*25;V=f(a/10);a-=V*10;W=f(a/5);a-=W*5;S+T+U+V+W+a;}` and enter `SOLVE("<your word>")`. This code disregards any non-lowercase, alphabetical, English letters.